# Code generation failed _ Qt Designer in : pyqt6-pyside6-python3.12.1

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6, pyqt6, qtpy

I have an issue with pyside6 and pyqt6 in Qt Designer that makes me so angry because I tried many ways to solve this problem but I Failed in all of them. when I want to open qt designer python code, I receive an error that I don't know how to fix it. An error about "unrecognized arguments: -g". My Python version is 3.12.1. I attached a picture of that error under this ticket.

[image]

I need to access the Python code of that GUI app (made by Qt designer), anyway.

Comment: I suppose you've installed the `pyqt6-tools` package, and you've also probably run the `Scripts/pyqt6-tools.exe installuic` command, right? How are you trying to display the code? You're not trying to open the "View Python Code..." menu item, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the UI file into python code properly. you can use the following from command line:

```
pyuic6 -o path_to_output.py -x path_to_input.ui
```

Or sometimes, if the `pyuic6` command is not found from the cli, you can do:

```
python -m PyQt6.uic.pyuic -o path_to_output.py -x path_to_input.ui
```

It will convert the UI file to python script that you can run.

Comment: Nice to hear that